# How can I solve Nuget DLL Hell - whatever I do VS inists that the dll version is different to that in the package

Tags: c#, nuget

I have been struggling for over a week now with DLL hell after a Nuget update.  I have managed to solve most of the problems by manually editing solution, project, and package files.  However, whatever I do VS insists that the version of the dll is different to the one installed by Nuget. The library in question is MailKit, which worked fine until the update.  Now the installed version is 2.4.1 but the property grid despite showing the correct location insists that the version 2.4.0:

[image: Property grid showing the incorrect version being displayed]

I have tried all of the following with no success at all:

- Update-Package -Reinstall
- Manually deleting the Nuget cache
- Manually deleting every single copy of the 2.4.0 dll on the computer
- Searching the entire code base for any reference to 2.4.0 and manually editing the code to remove the reference or renumber to the correct version
- Removing the Nuget cache from the command line
- Everything else I could find suggested as a solution on StackOverflow

Whatever I do, it still shows the wrong version, so when the app runs it throws an exception since the correct version is copied local.

Can anyone suggest how I might resolve this please?

**EDIT:**

Package Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="BouncyCastle" version="1.8.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="JetBrains.Annotations" version="2019.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MailKit" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MimeKit" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Project File (only references to the MailKit and MimeKit, the rest redacted as unnecessary, let me know if more is needed):

```
<Reference Include="MailKit, Version=2.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4e064fe7c44a8f1b, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\MailKit.2.4.1\lib\net45\MailKit.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="MethodExtensions, Version=1.0.4469.11621, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\Libraries\MethodExtensions\bin\Debug\MethodExtensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="MimeKit, Version=2.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bede1c8a46c66814, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\MimeKit.2.4.1\lib\net45\MimeKit.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

**Further Edit:**

For clarification, the dll version installed by the package is clearly 2.4.1:

[image: Properties of the referenced DLL]

Here is the runtime error message confirming that it is looking for 2.4.0 which is no longer on the computer following the Nuget update:

[image: Runtime error message]

**The Solution**

The answer from @zivkan pointed me in the right direction. Firstly I was looking for entirely the wrong thing, assuming that the version in the Property Grid was incorrect when in fact it was perfectly fine.  The reference is located in a plugin module which itself compiles to a library, which means that when compiling the MailKit dll not only has to be copied local but then copied to the main application folder using a post build event command line.  It turns out that there was an error in the post build event code so that MailKit was not copied and MimeKit was copied twice. Not taking the blame for that one, but I do take the blame for not recognising the problem!

Thanks, @zirkan, for your help and explanation which finally got me to the resolution...

Comment: Have tried including a bindingRedirect entry in your config file? That is usually (but not always) the first step on the path out of NuGet hell

Comment: The first step is to use New-Style Project References (not NuGet package files) with automatic binding redirects.. then *remove all local packages that are fulfilled by a transient dependency unless establishing a primary dependency/reference*. Finally, ensure all primary package references share the same version in the project files. For better or worse, the automatic bindings will “pull up” versions.

Comment: @Flydog57: I actually removed some old bindingRedirect entries that were not required... That was one of the processes I undertook in resolving other issues.  The burning question is what is causing the wrong dll to show...

Comment: @user2864740: Nuget does this stuff automatically, whereas I used always to update libraries manually.  What is a 'new style project reference' and how can I use them instead of package files given the Nuget does all that for itself?  Finally, this is a primary dependency and the only usage of MailKit in the solution.

Comment: NuGet packages with old style projects / packages do *not* do such automatically in a clean way - it’s a mess that stumbles over itself regularly. This is largely because before package references, transient dependencies are not handled well in VS projects - https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+project+to+package+references

Comment: Can you show your csproj/package.config?

Comment: Having Googled the term, it would seem that 'new-style project references' require VS 2017, I am still on 2015...

Comment: NIT: Binding redirects are a *runtime* artifact and won’t affect the project or NuGet package resolution. A bad binding redirect would cause issues when running, not compiling.

Comment: @oldcoder :( Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the app runs it throws an exception since the correct version is copied local.

Do you mean incorrect? I don't see why an exception will be thrown if the correct version is copied. In any case, it would have been more helpful if you showed us the actual error you got. I'm going to spend the rest of this answer explaining why everything else is working as designed, meaning you haven't given us enough information to understand your problem, so it's hard to suggest a good solution.

Anyway, a NuGet package is just a zip file (renamed `.nupkg`) that contains some files, usually some .NET assemblies. So, giving away the fundemental issue, what happens if the different assemblies in the package have different versions? The answer is nothing because assembly version and package version are independent. Often they're similar, or (almost) exactly the same, but since they're independent there's no reason they can't be different.

An assembly also has multiple versions. Firstly, if you find the `.dll` in Windows explorer, right click, select properties and go to the details tab, you'll see that all (or most) dlls have a product version and a file version. This is not specific to .NET, all windows executables have this metadata. If you use ILSpy or something similar to inspect the .NET assembly, you'll see there are AssemblyFileVersion, AssemblyInformationalVersion and AssemblyVersion attributes. So all together there are at least 5 different version metadata, and they're all independent and therefore can be different. That's before we consider NuGet package version is a 6th independent version number.

Now, the assembly in the properties window doesn't know anything about NuGet. It's showing you the path to the file, and since NuGet extracts packages to a path that includes the package version, we can see it in the path. But the version shows in the properties window is the assembly version. So, in this case the MailKit v2.4.1 package contains MailKit.dll with assembly version 2.4.0.0. Visual Studio's property window is showing you the correct information, there is no problem.

My answer is already long enough, so I won't go into a lot of details, but package authors may choose to use the same assembly version across multiple versions of their packages to minimise the number of times binding redirects are needed. However, this only works when the different product veresions are compatible. When they're incompatible and two different assemblies both have a dependency to the same assembly version of a dependency, it's impossible to load the two different versions at the same time to work around the problem (yes, when the same assembly has different assembly versions, it's possible to load both at the same time, it just takes extra effort).

Comment: The only copy of the dll in the location shown is version 2.4.1!  I had already checked this, and as stated in the original question one of the steps undertaken was to locate every copy of 2.4.0.0 on the PC and delete them.  So, the correct dll is stored in the correct location, it is only the property grid which is showing the wrong version.  The correct version (2.4.1) is copied from the package on build, and is placed in the correct location.  However, because somewhere it is referencing the old one it fails at runtime because there are NO COPIES of the wrong dll (2.4.0) on the PC...

Comment: I downloaded MailKit.2.4.1.nupkg, extracted one of the dlls and looked at the assembly version and it's 2.4.0.0. As far as I can tell, everything is working as designed. I still don't understand what runtime error you're experiencing.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the properties of the DLL, which is clearly 2.4.1...  am I still missing something?  The runtime error states that the system cannot find MailKit 2.4.0, which is not surprising since it is not there and should not be referenced at all! I am using the version compatible with .Net 4.5.2 which is the framework version in use.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there are 5 different concepts for "version" of a dll. Your edited question that shows the file properties window, which shows Windows PE metadata, which has 2 of the 5 versions. However, the .NET runtime cares only about the assembly version, which you can check using ILSpy or ILDasm or NuGet Package Explorer. MailKit v2.4.1 contains assembly version 2.4.0.0, which is what the runtime error claims is missing, which suggests the dll was not copied to the project output directory, or maybe is being configured not to load assemblies from.

Comment: You can use [fuslogvw.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to log assembly load information, and it will tell you which dlls it tried to load and explan why a dll that was found was not loaded.